# BSOD Crash, Driver issue found

Tags: windows-7, crash, bsod

So I kept getting a BSOD with "IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL"

I finally found a program called BlueScreenView to help me diagnose the issue.

This same BSOD happened multiple times, and BSV says that it is being caused by driver "ntoskrnl.exe" for every crash.

I run Windows 7 Ultimate.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Some insight to that error code here...http://www.geekswhoknow.com/articles/stop-0x0000000A-0x000000A-irql_not_less_or_equal.htm

Answer (score 2):

A common cause of that error is a bad memory module. Download the Free ISO file and burn it as an image to CD, boot from it and run memtest overnight to stress test the memory.

http://www.memtest.org/#downiso

.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

- applying any outstanding updates and see if that takes care of it.
- run a scan with MalwareBytes and see if any illicit software is installed.
- if you've recently installed software or drivers, roll them back until it no longer gives you this error.  Use System Restore to help you.
- Try disabling as many options/special features in your BIOS that you can without affecting your system's ability to boot

ntoskrnl.exe is the Windows 7 kernel.  One thing that immediately comes to mind is that if you're running an activation crack that has modified the kernel, that could also be the cause of it.